# How to install Ubuntu on second partition without USB or CD-ROM

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb

I want to install Ubuntu on my laptop which currently has Elementary OS on it. But I can't seem to get it to boot from USB, no matter what I try.

I want to reduce the size of the partition where I have Elementary OS installed, then create a new partition on which I will install Ubuntu 16.

I can't seem to find online what commands to run in terminal to make this happen. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can also try to boot directly from the `iso` file on your hard drive. See this link for more info `https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install Ubuntu, you can do the partition job inside the installation part.

You only need to do:

- A bootable usb with Ubuntu
- Go to the BIOS setup(google the button to press in your computer)
- Switch the tab to the one that shows "BOOT"
- Move the USB device to the first position(make sure you have plugged it)
- Don't let Ubuntu do anything automatically, always manual and pay attention to do properly the partition part

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Bechma's answer, on some computers there may be a quick button to press while the computer is booting (usually that few seconds where you see a brand name on a store bought computer) that puts you into a quick boot menu. This allows you to select where to boot from, USB, HDD, etc. On my Lenovo it works more reliably than the BIOS boot order for whatever reason. Its either F10 or F12 (honestly can't remember sometimes but will hit it when I use those buttons while booting. May be something else on a Dell). Also, if you want to shrink your current Elementary partition before you being your setup of another OS, you should be able to find GParted in the software center and use this as necessary to shrink the available space to create a new EXT4 partition. This will usually be available during the installation process as well though, if choosing "something else" option on the partitioning screen.